# Winsock select function returning different values

Tags: c++, winsock

I am working on project having client server architecture. select function returns different value in different scenarios Followings are the details

- Scenario 1:

  When i install my server at my machine, stop all the corresponding services, my client goes to DC state and now return value of select is 1 and read_mask.fd_count is also 1.
- Scenario 2:

  When i connect to remote server (abc.com) and disconnect my wireless connection. in this case the same function returns 0 also read_mask.fd_count is 0. i tried changing timeout variable value from ten ms to 50 sec. cant figure out the problem.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You *have* read the [`select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation? It states quite clearly what the possible return values are and what they mean.

Comment: Also, the internal data of a `fd_set` is just that, internal. You should only use the provided macros to access it.

Comment: yes i have read them, but cant exactly understand the difference between 0 and 1 in both cases the return value should be same (as it is not SOCKET_ERROR in both cases)

Comment: The `select` function returns zero on timeout (no matter the length of the timeout). It returns `1` when there is one socket ready in the returned sets. If you had two sockets ready then `select` would have returned `2`.

Comment: yes i can understand it, but my question now is why socket is not in ready state when i attempted dc from remote server? any idea?

Comment: If you have a socket in the read set, and `select` returns `0`, then it means that there haven't been anything received on that socket within the time you asked `select` to wait. It's a simple as that, you haven't received data. Why? That's something we can't answer, it all depends on the other end of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

When you shot down the server you cause the network stack to shutdown the connection. Furtehr connection request are refused. The `select` indicates that there's something and the the `recv()` returns 0 to indicate `forcibly closed`.

When you pull the wireless cable out of the plug then the client gets neither the shutdown nor the connection request. You wait for any timeout to detect the not available server.

In a real world application you should implement a kind of heartbeat in you protocol that allows to detect the "disconnected state" in the second scenario.

*Edit:* If your Winsock implementation supports [SO_KEEPALIVE_VALS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS__opcode_setting__I__T__3_), you can also configure this to detect the lost connectivity. See also: [SO_KEEPALIVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee470551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: In Second scenario, what method can be used to check if the server has disconnected?

Comment: @AliKazmi This is answered in my third paragraph.